# Check if a cell value is referenced by another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I have a google-sheet containing many sheets.
I reference the values of a specific column in all sheets in a summary-like sheet.
I need to check that I did not forget to reference one of the cells of this column, to do so, I wanted to create a Validation rule that will show the un-referenced cells.
Is there a way to achieve this ?